# Create a block numpy array from a numpy array of 2D numpy arrays efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

First a simple example

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((2,2))
b = 2*np.ones((2,2))
c = 3*np.ones((2,2))
d = 4*np.ones((2,2))
e = np.array([[a,b],[c,d]])
print(np.vstack(np.array([np.hstack(e[i,:]) for i in range(2)])))
```

which produces

```
[[ 1.  1.  2.  2.]
 [ 1.  1.  2.  2.]
 [ 3.  3.  4.  4.]
 [ 3.  3.  4.  4.]]
```

which is exactly the same as the result of `print(np.bmat(e.tolist()))` or `print(np.bmat([[a,b],[c,d]]))` (modulo the fact that `np.bmat` creates a numpy matrix which can be cast, using `np.asarray()`).

However, my problem is that I have a code where I create a large numpy array of 36 (for the moment, will become much more later, like 400) 2D numpy arrays and I want to create one big block numpy array out of them. I want to do this efficiently and if possible avoiding any conversions between lists and numpy arrays, as this is part of a bigger loop construction, hence will be done many times (the arrays are different each time). Is that possible?

Comment: ok, maybe I am not clear. Indeed, for the simple example this works. But in my real problem I create a big numpy array of 2D numpy arrays and I don't want to convert it to a list

Comment: If you have like 36 arrays, maybe it would make sense to initialize the o/p array and then iteratively slice into the o/p array and do the assignments?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean. The number of arrays is a function of a parameter that I plan on increasing in the near future, so it should be completely automatic

Comment: I meant you could initialize an o/p array, `out` of shape(4,4) and then slice and assign : `out[:2,:2] = a`  and so on. Would all the arrays be of the same shape?

Comment: All the arrays are of the same size, which I know (a function of a parameter that I set) and they are all square. Assigning like that will be inefficient once I start playing with 400 and more arrays, wouldn't it?

Comment: Your stacking could be simplified to `np.vstack([np.hstack(i) for i in [[a,b],[c,d]]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
np.swapaxes(e, 1, 2).reshape([4, 4])
```

If you examine the order in which elements should be drawn from `e` to produce our desired output, you'll find that we want to go along axis 3, then 1, then 2, then 0. `reshape` draws elements along axis 3, then 2, then 1, then 0, so we swap axes 1 and 2 before calling `reshape`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I was just going to edit my question and say that I have tried with reshape and it doesn't seem to work.